# Two level adjacency list using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im creating a new task and assign the parentid as 100 to that task, once created the newtask id is 101..

Now again i create a new task and assign 100 or 101 to that new id which is being created(102)

Now when i create new task whose id is 104 then it should give me an option to select 100,101 as the parent task id but not 102 since 102 is connected to 101 and 101 is connected to 100 parent id

How i can do this two level access?
My table structure is taskid ,parenttask id where task id is autoincrement ,primary key

So while getting the values from database how can i filter.
Below is my code.

```
<select name="mastertaskid" size="1" id="mastertaskid" STYLE="width: 350px" >
<option>Select One</option>

<?php 

$q = "SELECT * FROM Tasks order by Task_id asc";        
$r = mysql_query ($db, $q

if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
    // Check for stickyness:
    if (isset($return_val['ParentTask_Id']) 
       && ($return_val['ParentTask_Id'] == $row[0]) ) 
       echo ' selected="selected"'; 
    echo ">$row[1](<b>$row[0]</b>)</option>\n";
  }
}                                   
?>
</select>
```

Comment: FYI, your opening `<select>` tag does not match your closing `</seelct>` tag

Comment: Also, echoing HTML is a bad habit to get into, take a look at my version of this routine (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wb1JcdYL), it took me only a minute and is far more readable.

Comment: Oh, and your `$r = mysql_query ($db, $q` line is wrong, where's the `);` at the end?

Comment: Ok the </seelct> and ; can be taken care.But what is the logic ,please help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `Tasks` 
WHERE `ParentTask_id` = 0 OR `ParentTask_id` IN 
(SELECT `Task_id` FROM `Tasks` WHERE `ParentTask_id` = 0)
```

Comment: do you get an error? or is it returning the results you're not looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`... WHERE parent_task_id = 0` (or whatever the default value for that column is)

Comment: ... right. The code and description in your question are both incomplete. But my answer, pretty self-explaining for everybody who has ever written an SQL query is "not properly commented"? Don't expect to get a whole page of explanations for a question that you can google.